# Plotting Error bars in Mathematica 12

Tags: plotting

I have data sets form measurements with standard deviations

```
    time = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    data = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25}
    error = {.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1.2, 1.9}
```

which I would like to visualise using ListPlot with uncertainties option (new in Mathematica12).
For that I need to create a list such as

```
    {1±0.2±0.5,..., 25±1.9}
```

Any suggestions how to do that? creating list by hand and plotting it works fine, but that can't be the solution for some 100+ data points...
Or, what is the easiest way to make a plot with standard deviations when measurement data are organised in three separate list, i.e. x, y, error.

Thanks
Holger

Answer (score 7):

Use `MapThread` to combine all three lists together.

```
dataWithError = MapThread[{#1, Around[#2, #3]} &, {time, data, error}];
ListPlot[dataWithError];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 Also `ListPlot[{#[[1]], Around[#[[2]], #[[3]]]} & /@ Transpose[{time, data, error}]]`

Comment: great, works! Thanks so much, I replay appreciate it!

Comment: @Holger, great! If you find the answer valuable, consider accepting it (by clicking on the green tick).